# Checking incoming call in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, call

I have read about the [CoreTelephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603) class and in this [CTClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590) can check caller and find state of call....

But when and how to use this......

I think my application goes to background when call start..
help please or correct me......

Comment: You can detect when someone calls, but you can't check who's calling.  That would be a terrible breach of privacy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible with the official SDK. The best that you can do is determine if the user is on a call. You can do this by inspecting the size of the status bar frame.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame
```

Comment: When user is in a call then will our application run ?,,,sorry i think my app goes to background and does nothing...?

Comment: You application will go to the background, however the user can navigate to and open your application during their call.

Comment: the status bar frame is also higher than normal in tethering mode

Comment: @David  -- it means those your given method and methods in my question will work only when user will click our app during call ?

Comment: @Saawan, yes, then you can determine if the user is on a call. You can't however figure out the details of the call.

Comment: @David ---i give bounty on 50 points but you got only +25....why..can you give reason..

Answer (score 2):

If your asking if you can track phone calls in the background, you can't in all situations.

If you want to know if, at any point in time, when your running, you can.  You can access the 'CTCallCenter' currentCalls property and it will give you the state of the call at that point in time.

If you want to track if a incomming call the cause of your application going to the background, you can use the 'CTCallCenter' callEventHandler property.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish but after the call ends the user should automatically be brought back to the app.

Comment: i mean how can my application check that who is calling

Comment: The system doesn't give you access to the information about who's calling. I'm guessing specifically so that black hat apps can't spy on the user's calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get this information with the current SDK, most likely for privacy reasons. I'd recommend filing a feature request with Apple (http://radar.apple.com) however, I doubt it's something they're likely to include in the future.