# Modifying the Incoming Call screen in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, telephony, phone-call

I'm looking to design a simple app that categorizes contacts based on priority, and allow a different incoming screen to be displayed when that contact calls in depending on the contact's priority.  Is this achievable by using the Core Telephony library, or is this simply something that's forbidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps can only modify things within their own sandbox. The incoming call screen, is part of the phone app and therefore can't be modified. The only way to do this would be on a jailbroken iPhone, and it would be quite difficult.

There is no way to get an app like that on the Apple App Store.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm curious, though, does Apple provide any details about the implementation of the built-in Telephone app?  I'm kinda curious as to how it handles the information of the incoming caller, and so forth.

Comment: No there are no details on the Apple apps (like source code). I guess if they did it would only encourage jail brake apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can not identify incoming callers in the iPhone SDK for security reasons.
[this has a hack for that but still not legal]
[Checking incoming call in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601354/checking-incoming-call-in-iphone)